# Parsing webpage from android using jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

```
<meta property="og:description" content="At a very young age, life begins to change">
```

I want to scrap the above content in android using jsoup

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
String desc = document.select(query).text();
```

What will be the query?

Answer (score 0):

Before you start you must take a look inside jsoup cookbook https://jsoup.org/cookbook/

You can use the following code.

```
String html = "<meta property=\"og:description\" content=\"At a very youngage, life begins to change\">";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

String des = doc.select("meta").attr("content");
```